# where the .length key word in Java is defined in

Tags: java, arrays

Yeah i know that we use the .length keyword for counting the number of elements in an array, but actually the .length is. we all know that Java is an object oriented language which means whatever the thing that we talk about is an object.we know that we use the .length() method that is defined in the String class for counting the number of characters in a string object, but where the .length key word for arrays are defined in.

Comment: You're asking for the source for arrays?

Comment: I mean the length() method is defined in the String class, but where the .length key word is defined in.

Comment: Java being an object oriented language does not mean everything is an object. `length` itself is a _primitive_ field of the respective array, while `length()` would be a _method_ of the `String` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in Java are also classes and their instances are objects. Of course that's a special kind of Objects but as all other objects they have public fields and methods and `length` is a public field.

Also array class is extending Object class and have all methods from it like `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `toString()` etc.

Comment: Yeah that is my question. we use two brackets to indicate a method, but with the length key word we use nothing for arrays.

Comment: Yeah I got it........Thank you

Comment: Nice! You can also mark that as an unswer or upwote)